# Build Errors in Android Studio Gradle: It works fine when I remove the google dependency

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services

So I am assuming I have differing versions of dependencies causing this issue but i cant seem to resolve it.

When I add the dependency: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0' Then I get an error Syncing my build gradle.

When I change the version to implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.0' Then It Syncs fine but my app keeps crashing as soon as I open it.

Please can someone help me sync my versions so my app doesnt crash.

I changed the version from 18.0.0 to 15.0.0.

My gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ecommerce"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.sup`enter code here`port.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Tried the same gradle dependencies myself, but syncing works fine. Are you still getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I actually found out that Google stopped updating `com.google.android.gms:play-services` after 12.0.1. I changed the versions as well as my Firebase versions. Everthing Synced with no errors and seems to be running fine now.

Answer (score -1):

first go to file and sync project with gradle file.. if it repeat itself, then go to file and invalidate caches/Restart it has work for me alot of time and also try and replace  minSdkVersion 15 to minSdkVersion 21 and also with the look of it your firebase dependence are old check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup or google firebase dependencies
also make sure you add allprojects

```
 {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

}
to your build.gradle

Comment: After some research I actually found out that Google stopped updating com.google.android.gms:play-services after 12.0.1. I changed the versions as well as my Firebase versions. Everthing Synced and seems to be running fine now. I apprecaite the help nonethless Emi-Marfe!